# Looking for an elegant way to compare two lists and show differences from either side

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

Let's say I have two lists of strings.

```
List 1
- Item Abc
- Item Xyz
- Item BlahBlah

List 2
- Item Abc
- Item Xyz
- Item YadiYada
```

I want to show a table of matches and missing matches, something like this:

```
List 1          |   List 2
----------------------------------
Item Abc        |   Item Abc
Item Xyz        |   Item Xyz
Item BlahBlah   |
                |   Item YadiYada
```

I was thinking this could be done elegantly with LINQ, but I wasn't quite sure how to tackle it. I'd appreciate some direction on this.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far so that help can be provided where needed.

Comment: what about a set theory? `union` them then `.except()` by their `intersect`? while `intersect` will give you matches, such approach will give you all non-matches. -- `((List A) U (List B)) - ((List A) ∩ (List B))`

Comment: @BagusTesa, I see where you're going, but this only gives me the collection of those that aren't contained in the other list, which is only part of the answer. I also need those items that are only in List1 and those that are only in List2. This helped get me on the right track though!

Comment: Is the order of items important or subject to fudging, e.g. is 1, 2, 3 equal to 2, 1, 3 because it contains all of the same values? Are you using `List<string>` or some other collection of objects? If something other than strings, do you want to compare object references or do a deep comparison, i.e. different objects with the same property values match?

Comment: @HABO, no, the order is not important. It's more of a question of, are the items from List 1 contained in List 2, and vice-versa. if not, which ones are the ones missing, and from which list.  As far as which type of list I'm working with, well, it's actually a list of objects on one side, where one of the object properties is being compared to another list of strings. I simplified the matter here because the heart of my question was how to compare them.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var leftList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var rightList = new List<string>() { "2", "3", "4" };

var left = leftList.Except(rightList).Select(e => new { L = e, R = string.Empty });
var right = rightList.Except(leftList).Select(e => new { L = string.Empty, R = e });
var intersection = leftList.Intersect(rightList).Select(e => new {L = e, R = e});

var result = intersection.Union(left).Union(right).ToList();
```

Comment: Ah, i see. Makes a lot of sense. I will try to adapt this to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "Abc", "Xyz", "BlahBlah" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "Abc", "Xyz", "YadiYada" };

var r1 = from l1 in list1
         join l2 in list2 on l1 equals l2 into t
         from l2 in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { l1, l2 };

var r2 = from l2 in list2
         join l1 in list1 on l2 equals l1 into t
         from l1 in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { l1, l2 };

var result = r1.Union(r2);
```

[Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2)

This is an alternative using method syntax:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "Abc", "Xyz", "BlahBlah" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "Abc", "Xyz", "YadiYada" };

var r1 = list1
    .GroupJoin(
        list2,
        l1 => l1,
        l2 => l2,
        (l1, l2) => new { l1 = l1, l2 = l2.FirstOrDefault() });

var r2 = list2
    .GroupJoin(
        list1,
        l2 => l2,
        l1 => l1,
        (l2, l1) => new { l1 = l1.FirstOrDefault(), l2 = l2 });

var result = r1.Union(r2);
```

[LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947(v=vs.100).aspx)

> In general, we recommend query syntax because it is usually simpler
>   and more readable; however there is no semantic difference between
>   method syntax and query syntax. In addition, some queries, such as
>   those that retrieve the number of elements that match a specified
>   condition, or that retrieve the element that has the maximum value in
>   a source sequence, can only be expressed as method calls.

Comment: How would you write this using LINQ extension syntax (with lambda expressions)?